# Multiple Website Lampp Stack

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, wordpress

I currently have a Xampp on my local machine(ubuntu) for web developpment, this one is for study.
Then I have, before the Xampp, a lampp stack with wordpress for work.
After setting up Xampp my apache2/wordpress website stop working properly, giving me php pages without executing it.

I would like to know what is the best way to have 2 website on my computer? 1 with Wordpress and 1 with just my custom php pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into Virtual hosts.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Comment: thanks that's what i need